# What means "Verifies the write" when erasing hdd's?

Tags: c, io, hard-drive

Im looking at some code for (secure) erasing harddrives. I notice when looking at the different methods (**Infosec 5**, **DoD 5220.22-M**, etc.) i read "Verify the write".

examples:

https://www.lifewire.com/dod-5220-22-m-2625856

> Pass 3: Writes a random character and verifies the write

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infosec_Standard_5#cite_note-5

> Regardless of which level is used, verification is needed to ensure
>   that overwriting was successful.

My question is, what does it **technical** imply?

1. Do you just check when you write a block of data, if the bytes written are equal the size of the block (seems fast)?
2. Do you read back the block you wrote and compare (memcmp?) if its exactly same as the block of data written?
3. any other solution i overlooked?

Here a bit of *sample* code to illustrate my question. Which solution would indicate "verify on write"? If you only check the return value (from `write`) can **you be sure**, as long is matches the length of the block that *all* bytes are indeed written?

```
// erasure example
// erasure single block, start from 0

// block size
unsigned long block_size = 512;

// data-block we will write
char block[block_size];

// zero the block
bzero(&block, block_size);

// open device
int fd = open('/dev/sdb', O_RDWR);   

// write 1st block
int bytes_written = write(fd, &block, block_size);  

// verify option: A
if (bytes_written == block_size) {
    // all good
}

// verify option B
// go back the number of bytes-wtitten from the current pos.
lseek(fd, -1 * bytes_written);
// read the same number of bytes
int bytes_read = read(fd, &block, bytes_written);  

// should be same
if (bytes_read == bytes_written) {
    // here code to check i block indeed contains zero's    
    // use memcmp ?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*What means “Verifies the write” when erasing hdd's?*

From *[Here](ftp://gd.tuwien.ac.at/languages/c/programming-bbrown/c_075.htm)*

> The `write(...)` function attempts to write nbytes from buffer to the
>   file associated with handle. On text files, it expands each LF to a
>   CR/LF.
>
> The function returns the ***number of bytes written to the file***. A return
>   value of -1 indicates an error, with errno set appropriately.

So in your example, `int bytes_written = write(fd, &block, block_size);`
the value for bytes_written, if equal to the block size, *verifies* that all memory locations of block have been written to.

And in answer to your other questions:

- (1) Always check the return value of a non-void function anyway, and there is no significant efficiency or speed loss by simply performing a compare of two `int` values.  You can even do it in one step, but I am not sure it is an efficiency gain (view the assembly to know for sure).  So instead of:

  `// verify option: A

  if (bytes_written == block_size) 
  { 
      // all good 
  }`
  //You can do the comparison in the same line:

  `if(write(fd, &block, block_size) == block_size) { // all good }`
- (2) Optional..  It provides an *additional verification* that the memory block contains the new contents.

You can find a more detailed description of write() in *[this Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/write)*.

Comment: thank you, my point is more, does the return value (if block_size ==  write(...)) does that qualify, within the spec of erasure, as a verify.

Comment: @Rogier - Yes, either method, `if(block_size == write(...))` or `if(bytes_written == block_size)` are a clear indication ( _validation_ )  that the _change_ has been made.  Additional steps such as `memcmp(...)` would just provide additional verification, and are completely optional for your purpose, IMO.  I have modified my answer in attempt to make these thoughts more clear.

Comment: @Rogier - I am curious if your avatar image is of a _[Thunder Mustang](http://www.thundermustang.com/)_, or a full scale WWII plane?

Comment: i'm not sure, i picked it up somewhere :o I think its a P51 (full). I do have my PPL.  The P51 is on my bucket-list! You fly a experimental/kit?

Comment: @Rogier -  Cool.  And yes I would like to.  Just sold a Cessna, would like to purchase a partially constructed RV-8.